# jQuery Menu from UL

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need a menu that looks like a select box, but is made from a UL generated by Wordpress.  Rather than converting it to an actual select box, which creates style issues, I want to use jQuery show/hide.

I couldn't find any jQuery plugin made for this - to make a little select menu from a UL.  The look I want eventually is like this: http://shaggysmile.github.com/jQueryCoreUISelect/.  But this plugin uses an actual select box, and I'm in Wordpress using a UL.

Here's the Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/uthNv/1/

I need to replace this line of code with something better:

```
if($(this).next('li').is(':hidden') == true) {
```

The problem with using the next LI is that the last menu item doesn't work.  Any suggestions please, or knowledge of a jQuery plugin that already does what I need?

Comment: Please could you add an answer rather than update your question. This is to avoid confusion for future visitors. It's also a good idea to bring relevant code into the answer instead of hiding it behind a link just in case that link dies. Thank you.

Comment: The question 4 years old and obsolete. Is there no way to just remove them?

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as that I'm afraid. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this: http://jsfiddle.net/uthNv/2/

```
if($(this).siblings('li:hidden').length) {
```

Issue in your condition was `it was checking only the next li which is hidden` not the prev li so instead `if you use .siblings() which is at same level` that would work.

in this condition you can check the `.length` of the hidden li if that is true then your else statement will get executed.

Comment: That works, thanks!  I know that I am going to run into more issues - do you happen to know of a plugin that would do this simple thing?  That will scroll, and go to the URL, etc?

Comment: why do you need a plugin for that use `.slideUp()`  and `.slideDown()` for animating it instead of `.show()` and `.hide()`

Comment: I'm not really worried about the animation, but about scrolling, setting the nav to current page, making it disappear when click outside, features like that.  I have searched for 2 days for plugin, but all of them seem to use select box html.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement.